# Argument axis labels in DevExpress charts not appearing when day scale is set

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, devexpress

We've encountered following behaviour when using 13.2 (we can't update yet) charts.

The chart is a `line chart`, with `DateTime` arguments and `double` values, value's `ScaleType` is `Numerical`, argument's `ScaleType` is `DateTime`.

The `DataSource` contains around 50 points where 30 of them are on first day (ex. 2016-07-13) and rest are on second day (ex 2016-07-14) - usually 30 min intevrals.

We let the user change the the scale (`MeasureUnit`, `GridAlignment` - both simultaneously) between minutes, hours and days.

Now, we've got 2 situations:

First, the incorrect behaviour:

1. User opens the form with the chart, the first series has no values, chart is empty, the scale is set to hours.
2. User changes the series (via combobox), the chart has values now, everything is ok.
3. User changes the scale to days, the arguments (x-axis) labels disappear, no matter which series is drawn.
4. User changes the scale to hours or minutes, labels are drawn correctly for these 2 scales.
5. User changes the scale to days again, still no labels.

[image: The invalid behaviour]

Second, the "working" behaviour:

1. User opens the form with the chart, **the first series has no values** (this is important, if the first visible series has values, it's not working), chart is empty, the scale is set to hours.
2. User **changes the scale** to days (notice we set the scale first, then the series)
3. User changes the series (via combobox), the chart has values now, everything is ok, the argument's axis has the lables.
4. Now we can switch between scales, series etc. and everthing is working.

[image: The valid behaviour]

In the pictures you can see the same chart, the same series, just two different approaches.

Comment: try  chart1.ResetAutoValues();

Comment: Sorry there is no method `ResetAutoValues` for `ChartControl`

Comment: oh,sorry.It's available for MS charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this set the following properties:

```
AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.AutoGrid = false;
AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.GridSpacing = 1.0; // This may differ
```

For some reason, in random (for me) cases the GridSpacing has been set to 8.0 which caused the labels to disappear.